# Why data Shadowing with instance variables is not working in my program?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, scope

I have three classes which are shown below ,for a game GUI:-

```
//this is the parent class.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class GameGui extends JFrame{
      public void decorateButton(JButton aBut,Color forg,Color back){
         Font afont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.PLAIN,18);
         aBut.setFont(afont);
         aBut.setBackground(back);
         aBut.setForeground(forg);
      }
      public void setFrameDefault(){
         this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         this.setSize(400, 475);
         this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         this.setResizable(false);
     }
     public void setConstraints(int x,int y,int weightx,int weighty,GridBagConstraints gbc){
         gbc.weighty=weighty;
         gbc.weightx=weightx;
         gbc.gridx=x;
         gbc.gridy=y;
     }
}

//this class is for result to be shown for the game.

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Result extends GameGui{
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      JLabel backImage = new JLabel();//I want this variable to be shadowed by the subclass variable,but it is not happening. 
      JButton continueGame = new JButton("continueGame");
      JButton exitGame = new JButton("exitGame");
      public Result(){
            this.setFrameDefault();
            backImage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setContentPane(backImage);
            mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            decorateButton(continueGame,Color.green,Color.white);
            decorateButton(exitGame,Color.green,Color.white);
            setGui();
      }
      public void setGui(){
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
            gbc.gridy=200;
            gbc.gridx=0;
            gbc.insets=new Insets(410,0,0,130);
            mainPanel.add(continueGame,gbc);
            gbc.gridx=GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(410,0,0,0);
            mainPanel.add(exitGame,gbc);
            setFrameDefault();
            this.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      }

 }

 //this class is for showing the result for a Win.

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 public class Win extends Result{
        JLabel backImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\BSK\\Desktop\\win.png"));//Problem is here as i have declared the same named JLabel as in Result class but iam not getting the image as background.
        public static void main(String[] args) { //this main method is for testing.
            Win w = new Win();
            w.setVisible(true);
        }
 }
```

I need two classes at end of hierarchy which are `Win` and `Defeat`(second one i have not implemented).I need this because i want wining frame and Defeat frame only differ in the image.
So my question is that although i have declared same named JLabel as `backImage` in both the classes `Result` and `Win`,why i am not getting the image at background?I have tested it by putting the image  in `JLabel` `backImage` of `Result` class and then it works!But i want to take the advantage of **data shadowing** because in my `Defeat` class(which also extends Result)i will name `JLabel` having same name as `backImage` but with different image set to it.I hope you understand,So what is the way out?
Thanks in advance.

**NOTE** please test with your image.

Comment: It looks like you're misusing inheritance here: that you're using inheritance where composition would be better.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if you can provide a detailed answer......many many many thanx

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels plese if you can describe....waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Shadowing affects which variable a name refers to. That is, since the subclass `Win` defines its own `backImage` instance variable, methods of `Win` that refer to `backImage` will refer to the instance variable in `Win` (and thus its value) rather than the one in the superclass, `Result`.

Shadowing does not replace an object that variables and other objects point to. That is, the superclass `Result` still defines its own `backImage` instance variable, and `Result`'s methods still refer to that variable (and thus its value). So `Win#backImage` shadows `Result#backImage` but it doesn't change how Result works.

Also note that the initialization lines like `JLabel backImage = ...` run as part of a class's constructor, and the subclass `Win`'s constructor begins by running its superclass `Result` constructor. So if the subclass didn't declare another `backImage` and its constructor assigned a new value to the inherited instance variable `Result#backImage`, this would happen after the `Result` constructor built the content pane, so it wouldn't change the display.

You could change the contents of the `backImage` object:

```
public class Win extends Result {
  public Win() {
    super();
    backImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\BSK\\Desktop\\win.png"));
  }

  ...
```

to modify backImage's icon for the `Win` subclass.

Comment: please elaborate your first line..if you can...thanks

Comment: Elaborated. The code might also have to request a window relayout after changing the label's icon.

Comment: you are saying that `Win` class will refer to its own JLabel but then why the result is not as expected?

Comment: No. The Win class should not declare its own backImage variable nor create another instance of JLabel. Just change the icon of the existing JLabel that's already linked into the component tree.

Comment: BTW, the post above answers the question about what shadowing does and doesn't do, and offers a minimal code change. A better design could omit the subclass (that isn't a good use of subclassing) and either add a `Result` method to change its background or add a `Result` constructor parameter to specify the background. The latter case may optionally have a no-arg constructor that always uses the default background.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in Java don't get overriden as methods, so this will not work for you. Fortunately, there are plenty solutions.

One of them (i'm definetly not saying the best one!) is to make your `Result` game abstract with abstract `getIcon()` method or something and call that from your `setGui()` method, then your Win/Lose classes will just return different icons in there.

Comment: but this is not overriding and how would `Result` class uses its other Methods if we don't have `JLabel` defined there?

Comment: The JLabel would still be delared inside `Result` class, and the method `getIcon()` will also be declared in there, just initialize your background in `setGui()` but instead of specific Icon, use your `getIcon()` method. Then override it in your `Win` class to return the icon you acctually want.

Comment: Although `Win` could override a `Result#getIcon()` method, it's generally a bad idea to override a method that's called by a constructor because it gets called before the subclass constructor runs. This could be fixed by doing the UI building work after the constructor.

Comment: aaa, true, i wanted t oadd warning that it is terrible idea to call overridable methods from constructor (from own experiance), i didn't notice `setGui()` was called from constructor.